# how do i query page fan information from the graph api?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I used to be able to query /insights and see a lot of information including page_fans_locale and page_fans_gender_age and many others. Recently (in the past month or two) the document returned from the /insights query has been stripped down to just page_story_adds_unique, page_storytellers, page_admin_num_posts and page_admin_num_posts_by_type.

I have tried querying for /insights/page_fans_gender_age directly as well as /insights/page_fans_gender_age/lifetime. While i do get a valid response, its always empty no matter which page i'm selecting for.

It seems like there have been some changes to the api since I last looked at it. I'm not sure if there is something preventing the information from being returned or if those actions have been removed and I'm only not getting an error because of something legacy in the api.

Regardless of the code I already had written, is it still possible to query this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Facebook API bug has reappeared again.  Relevant link: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/345809555540652?browse=search_5148c3f9aa0392220388804

Initial post:

Short answer: Yes.  Make sure you have "read_insights" permission etc. and try again.

Long answer: One of my websites was having issues today because requests such as the original poster's were suddenly coming back with null values.  Whatever the issue was, it appears to have been on Facebook's side, and has since been resolved.

Moral of the story: Be incredibly hesitant to build applications that are heavily dependent on calls to other people's APIs.  Especially so with facebook.

Comment: your update with the link to the facebook bug was basically exactly what i was looking for... this sucks but at least i know whats going on now. thank you.